# tableview cell addition stating invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, append

Every time i hit the add button cell. A new cell should be added to the tableview right now when the user taps the add button the entire code goes into a runtime error. I would like to fix the error so that you can add a cell to the tableview. The runtime error states

> "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of
> rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be
> equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
> update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
> that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus  or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

```
import UIKit
 

 
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
 
    

    var addBTN = UIButton()
    var arr = [1,1,3,3]
    var currentIndex = 0
    var arrayValues = [Int]()
    
   
    

 
    var pic = UIImageView()
    var addBtn = UIButton()
    var cellCount = 5
    var tableview = UITableView()

    
    
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellCount // use a variable here so you can change it as you delete cells, else it will crash
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 118
    }
   
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTv
        
   
        return cell
    }
    

    
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        [addBTN].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        tableview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height * 0.8)
        addBTN.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: view.frame.height * 0.8, width: view.frame.width / 2  , height: view.frame.height / 5)
        addBTN.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
      
        view.addSubview(tableview)

 
        tableview.register(CustomTv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        pic.isHidden = true
        pic.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height )
        
      
        addBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newCell), for: .touchDown)
        
        
        addBTN.setTitle("New cell", for: .normal)
    }
    @objc func newCell(){
        
        arr.append(6) /// not sure what the numbers mean though...
        tableview.beginUpdates()
        tableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: arr.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic) /// animate the insertion
    tableview.endUpdates()

    }
    
}



protocol CustomTvCellDelegateadd: AnyObject {
    func addCeller(_ customTV: CustomTv)
}
class CustomTv: UITableViewCell { // it's good form to Pascal case your class name ;)
    
    weak var delegate: CustomTvCellDelegate? // make that delegate a property of your cell
    weak var delegatef: CustomTvCellDelegateadd?
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        
        return view
    }()



        lazy var pic : UIImageView = {
            let btn = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50-25, y: 6, width: 100 , height: 110))
            btn.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    
            return btn
    
        }()


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backView.clipsToBounds = true
        backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
        
        // moved these calls here instead of on setSelected(_selected:animated:)
        addSubview(backView)
       

        backView.addSubview(pic)
        
        

        
 
      
    }
        @objc func addButtonTapped() {
            self.delegatef?.addCeller(self)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you appended a value (6) to array called arr but when tableView asked for number of rows in section you returned `cellCount` which you never bothered to increment so it will continue to return 5.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellCount // use a variable here so you can change it as you delete cells, else it will crash
    }
```

so when `tableview.insertRows` is executed, tableView expects number of rows to be incremented by number of elements in array (in your case it expects number of rows to be 6 but because of unchanged value of  `cellCount` it will get only 5 hence tableView has no idea and throws error mentioning

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
> (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
> before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or
> deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus
> the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0
> moved out)."

so either change

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
```

or use

```
@objc func newCell(){
        cellCount += 1 // update the value
        arr.append(6)
        tableview.beginUpdates()
        tableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: arr.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic) /// animate the insertion
    tableview.endUpdates()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellCount
}
```

whichever makes more sense to you :)